# How to find children within this <a> parent?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get text inside `.fromTo` but the script doesn't work.

Do I think correctly if the first part goes to the `<a>` element. And then it will search for the child and then get the text?

**jQuery**

```
to_user = $("a#"+msg_id).find("div.fromTo").text()
```

**html**

```
<a href="" id="27" class="msgLink">
    <div style="background:url(/media/user_avatar/comment_thumbnails/8.png);" class="msgImg"></div>
    <div class="fromTo">spelia</div>
    <div class="messageBody">wdwdwdw</div>
    <div class="message_date">8 hours ago</div>
    <div class="clearIt"></div>
</a>
```

Comment: I don't think this is why it is not working, but IDs should not start with a number according to the spec. The code does look like it should work, though.

Comment: @Jason look at how Facebook messages page looks like. I actually took that idea from them, since I lacked fantasy of how to model the divs ;)

Comment: @starcorn dear god, you're right. i'm going to be ill.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but it's probably better to use <a href="" data-message-id="<ID>" class="msgLink">. Just to eliminate the possibility of having multiple elements in the DOM with the same id. Could consequently make jQuery selection easier too.

Comment: @Jason, anchor tags are allowed to have block level elements in html5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `#id` syntax works if you access directly through id. If you want to access tag name first then give id (or any other attribute) then following way will work

```
to_user = $("a[id='"+msg_id+"']").find("div.fromTo").text();
```

Similarly you can access an element with any attribute

`$("a[attribute_name='"+desired_value+"']")`

You can details here http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder your link works. But I have seen people facing problem while using `tagname#id` syntax. Any expert advise/suggestion is welcome

Comment: `tagname#id` would work but is much slower so it's not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

While @Imdad is completely right here. Because ID's are unique by definition, including the tag name is extraneous. Just use `'#'` instead of `'a#'`

```
 to_user = $("#"+msg_id).find("div.fromTo").text()
```

If you have multiple types of tags with the same id (and thus need to query both tag name and id to get the element), you are going to have problems and really should be using a class instead or data- attribute instead.